# Put an image between a ul (menu)

Tags: css, image

I'm doing a site in HTML, the front-end part, but I want to do menu with between a logo.
I tried with following

```
position:absolute; 
top:180px; 
right:300px;
```

But it's not responsive and I think it's a bad way to do that, I tried with the `%` but when I change the size of the window the logo isn't centered.

I simply put the logo in a ul and used `vertical-align` but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you.

This is my code

The HTML code is

```
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu1">
        <li><a href="">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="menu2">
        <li><img src"image.png" alt=""/></li>
        <li><a href="">Section 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Section 4</a></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

and the CSS is

```
#nav
{
 background-color:red;
 width:550px;
 height:150px;

 }

   #menu1, #menu2
   {
    list-style:none;
    }

    #menu1 li a 
    {
     text-decoration:none;
     font-size:18px;
     float:left;
     margin-top:50px;
     margin-right:10px;
     margin-left:10px;
    }

     #menu2 li a 
     {
      text-decoration:none;
      font-size:18px;
      float:right;
      margin-top:35px;
      margin-left:10px;
      margin-right:10px;
      }

      img
       {
       width:235px;
       height:196px;
       display:inline-block;
       position:absolute;
       margin-left:365px;

       }
```

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I wrote the code, but I didn't use jsfiddle because I don't know how to add an image from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Already, the code for inserting the image is not good :

```
<img src="image.png" alt=""/>
```